# Why does my Validation Script continue to run when adding the result to the map?

Tags: arcpy, imagery, select-by-location, array, tool-validation

I am in the process of developing a python script that creates a list available imagery for our project areas that would then allow the user to choose which imagery source they would like to add to a map.  My idea to accomplish this was to use a validation script to add an index layer to the map and create a polygon from an array and then do a select by location. A list of available imagery would be created.  I have gotten the validation script to create the list, but the problem comes in after selecting the imagery to add.  As far as I can tell the validation script runs again to every selection and after the initial run.  Below is the validation script:

```
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    import arcpy
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    # Define the map document and data frame
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
    frameExtent = df.extent

    #Data Frame Array
    XMAX = frameExtent.XMax
    XMIN = frameExtent.XMin
    YMAX = frameExtent.YMax
    YMIN = frameExtent.YMin
    pnt1 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMIN)
    pnt2 = arcpy.Point(XMIN, YMAX)
    pnt3 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMAX)
    pnt4 = arcpy.Point(XMAX, YMIN)
    array = arcpy.Array()
    array.add(pnt1)
    array.add(pnt2)
    array.add(pnt3)
    array.add(pnt4)
    array.add(pnt1)
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)

    #Add ImageryIndex Layer
    imgIndexLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'\\mdcfcs2\gisdept\GIS_Department\GIS_Users\HartmanB\Projects\2015\!ImageryProject\ImageryIndex.gdb\ImageryIndex')

    #Select ImageryIndex features by data frame corners
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(imgIndexLayer, 'INTERSECT', polygon)

    field = "ImagePath"
    cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("ImageryIndex", field)
    imageryList = [str(val) for val in
                     sorted(
                       set(
                         row[0] for row in cursor
                           )
                         )
                   ]
    self.params[0].filter.list = imageryList

    #Remove Layers
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
        if lyr.name == "Polygon_Extent" or lyr.name == "ImageryIndex":
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

Comment: According to the help page _Customizing script tool behavior_ initializeParameters should run once when the tool is open, try putting some message boxes to confirm this?

Comment: I ran the validation script in the python window in arcmap with a print function at the end and the script ran in 0.67 seconds and only added the index layer once.  When running the entire tool the time it takes to run is significant.  @Hornbydd

Comment: @B.Hartman ToolValidator is no do for that use... First, work only with parameters passed as argument. If you need to manage events, use the addin that are more suitable. ToolValidator is for validate a parameter or auto fix or load other parameter with specifics conditions

Comment: Is this tool validation from a Python script tool in a standard toolbox (`*.tbx`) or a Python toolbox (`*.pyt`).  Either way I think you should try trimming down the code snippet that you are presenting here.